# ChromiumWebBrowser flash black after hiding without disabling WebGL

Tags: winforms, webgl, cefsharp

I am trying to hide my ChromiumWebBrowser behind images, video, etc... But every time it changes from a ChromiumWebBrowser to anything else than a blank panel or another ChromiumWebBrowser it flashes black for a few frames.

[Exemple of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwdhe.gif)

hardware:

- i7-8559U
- intel IRI plus Graphics 655

CefSharp Version 79.1.350 for a Winform Program

Here is what I tried:

- BringToFront other PictureBox
- SendToback the ChromiumWebBrowser
- Panel visibility
- Panel doubleBuffed

I also enable Cef.EnableHighDPISupport(); but to no success.

The only thing that worked so far is to ADD
SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();

But unfortunately, it disables WebGL implementation :/ and I would like to keep it for later purposes.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Point d'entrée principal de l'application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}

 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private static ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;
    private PictureBox ImageBox = new PictureBox();

    private Panel pPictureBox = new Panel();
    private Panel pChromium = new Panel();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);

        ImageBox.Image = Properties.Resources._3080;
        ImageBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pPictureBox.Controls.Add(ImageBox);
        ImageBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        pPictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pPictureBox.Size = this.Size;
        this.Controls.Add(pPictureBox); 
        pPictureBox.BringToFront();

        InitializeChromium();

        timer.Interval = 7000;
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pChromium.Visible)
        {
            pChromium.Hide();   
        }
        else
        {
            pChromium.Show();
        }
    }

    private void InitializeChromium()
    {


        pChromium.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pChromium.Size = this.Size;
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

        //Work but disable WebGL
        //settings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();

        //settings.DisableGpuAcceleration();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.apple.com/ca/airpods-pro/");

        pChromium.Controls.Add(chrome);
        this.Controls.Add(pChromium);

        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        pChromium.BringToFront();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1904, 1041);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Do you guys have any solution?

Comment: Please include the version you are using. SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs should only be used for WPF and OffScreen versions.

Comment: Disabling GPU acceleration should switch to using swiftshader for webgl,  so will use software rendering.

Comment: Have you tried on different hardware?  Often this sort of issue is graphics card/driver related.

Comment: @amaitland Your solution does seem to work but it disables GPU graphics for ChromeWebbrowser WebGL and the renderer is only relying on my workstation CPU for render. I am gonna try testing the code at home to see if it fixes (i7-4770k and GTX 1070).

Comment: I wasn't aware I was proposing a solution, just providing a clarification. I've updated the outdated source comments in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/8706aadd3f4d2effc563cc5158734e66639c5293

Comment: Make sure you have the latest graphics drivers, you can experiment with https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#use-angle and https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#in-process-gpu I'd suggest you call `Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();` much earlier in your applications execution as calling it too late will do nothing. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs#L18

Comment: What exactly is a `BufferedPanel`?

Comment: Your example code is incomplete,  please provide a complete example. It doesn't compile.

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code in isolation? There's no `pictureBox2` declared anywhere, please make sure it compiles yourself. Use a standard panel for the `ChromiumWebBrowser`, double buffering is not something the control supports.

Comment: I can confirm that this bug still happens with this code on my computer at home (i7-4770k / GTX 1070)

Comment: I am gonna experiment with https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#use-angle Tomorrow.

Comment: Code still relies on a resource that's not included,  if you can fork https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample push changes to GitHub then I'll have a look if I get time.

Comment: the resource is an image pick any

Comment: @amaitland after experimenting with the peter.sh command both of them works on the Initial computer harware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final code for any one interested

Links of the command recommanded by @amaitland

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#use-angle
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#in-process-gpu

both command works individualy

Cef.EnableHighDPISupport(); is not required but is recommanded

```
static void Main()
    {
        Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private static ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;
    private PictureBox ImageBox = new PictureBox();

    private Panel pPictureBox = new Panel();
    private Panel pChromium = new Panel();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);

        //any image here
        ImageBox.Image = Properties.Resources._3080;
        ImageBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pPictureBox.Controls.Add(ImageBox);
        ImageBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        pPictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pPictureBox.Size = this.Size;
        this.Controls.Add(pPictureBox);
        pPictureBox.BringToFront();

        InitializeChromium();

        timer.Interval = 7000;
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pChromium.Visible)
        {
            pChromium.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            pChromium.Show();
        }
    }

    private void InitializeChromium()
    {


        pChromium.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pChromium.Size = this.Size;
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();


        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("in-process-gpu");

        //got best FPS with this renderer on "my machine"
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("use-angle", "gl");

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //Work but disable WebGL
        //settings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();
        //settings.DisableGpuAcceleration();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_pasta.html");

        pChromium.Controls.Add(chrome);
        this.Controls.Add(pChromium);

        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        pChromium.BringToFront();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1904, 1041);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: If use-angle works then that's the option I'd go with, in process gpu isn't generally used on Windows.

Comment: "use-angle", "gl" is not compatible in VMware any alternative???